# Where can I find all {{ codes }} that can be used in pages/blocks/cms content?

Tags: magento2

For example I know of

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

But where can I find documentation on all available features of this template language?
What other arguments can I use for {{ block }} etc.

Answer (score 0):

[The official Magento 2 documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/blocks.html) doesn't specify this. But, I think you can typically access all public fields of the base block class. If you are on a dev environment, their might be an error output even, if you use a wrong attribute. That error output probably shows, which attributes you are allowed to use.

Comment: There does not seem to be an error output, it just does not load in dev mode.
Where can I find class documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The class responsible for parsing the **{{ }}** directives in
CMS Blocks and Pages is `\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\Filter`
which extends `\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter`.
In the latter the following directives are implemented:

- block
- layout
- view
- media
- store
- trans
- var
- protocol
- config
- customvar
- css
- inlinecss
- widget

The last one is provided by the Widget module.

You can find some more info in [this section](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html) the official Magento docs